# Storing userId: state vs context vs asyncstorage

Tags: react-native, state, asyncstorage, userid

How would you recommend storing userId (logged in user) and having child components respond to this?

With state and context the child components re-render if this value changes. I think the advantage of context is that you don't have to pass props through every component; i.e. you have a 'redux-like' global state. With asyncstorage you don't have the re-renders but I think it is desirable? To be honest I struggle to understand why you would ever use asyncstorage when you can use useContext.. Can someone provide clarity?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/). It is redux without passing props.